# How to get the second derivative of implicit function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Equation:

```
 x^2 + (y[x])^2 - 1 == 0
```

Q:

```
y''[x]=?
(*the answer should be y''[x] = -1/y[x]^3*)
```

However,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eqn = x^2 + (y[x])^2 - 1 == 0;
Solve[D[eqn, {x, 2}], y''[x]] // FullSimplify

(*(y''[x] -> -((1 + y'[x]^2)/y[x])*)
```

Or,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eqn = x^2 + (y[x])^2 - 1 == 0;
sol1 = Solve[D[eqn, x], y'[x]]
sol2 = Solve[D[eqn, {x, 2}], y''[x]] /. sol1 // Simplify


(*{{y'[x]-> -(x/y[x])}}*)
(*(y''[x] -> -((x^2 + y[x]^2)/y[x]^3)*)
```

The `y''[x]` result is not simplified.

Answer (score 4):

It is simplified, but you haven't told it specifically how to substitute for x.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
xrule = {x -> Sqrt[1 - y[x]^2]}
eqn = x^2 + (y[x])^2 - 1 == 0;
sol1 = Solve[D[eqn, x], y'[x]]
sol2 = Solve[D[eqn, {x, 2}], y''[x]] /. sol1 /. {x^2 -> (x^2 /. xrule)} // Simplify

{x -> Sqrt[1 - y[x]^2]}
{{y'[x] -> -(x/y[x])}}
{y''[x] -> -(1/y[x]^3)}
```

Comment: Thanks. But we need to calculate x -> Sqrt[1 - y[x]^2] first. Is there a simpler way? @Bill Watts

Comment: @lotus2019 are you asking Bill if there is a way to automatically calculate such a replacement? I don’t see what you mean by needing to calculate the `xrule` first. As Bill notes, this is the replacement you need to tell mathematica to use if you want it to be simplified further.

Comment: I mean, if you can't find the expression of x, can't you simplify the result y''[x] -> -((x^2 + y[x]^2)/y[x]^3)? I don't think we need to get the expression for x:  {x -> Sqrt[1 - y[x]^2]}. And we don't even need to solve the y'[x] first. There should be simpler ways to get result y''[x] = -1/y[x]^3. @CA Trevillian

Comment: Mathematica can't read your mind as to what final form you want.  You have to tell it the variables to eliminate.

Comment: Thanks. @Bill Watts

Answer (score 3):

Another way. Substitute y[x],y'[x]... for intermediate calculations and eliminate x and y'[x].

```
eqn = x^2 + (y[x])^2 - 1 == 0;

ysubst = {y[x] -> z, y'[x] -> zt, y''[x] -> ztt}

Reduce[{eqn, D[eqn, {x, 1}], D[eqn, {x, 2}]} /. ysubst, 
                  ztt, {zt, x}, Reals] /. Reverse /@ ysubst

(*   (-1 <= y[x] < 0 && (y''[x] == -(1/y[x]^3)) || 
      (0 < y[x] <= 1 && (y''[x] == -(1/y[x]^3))   *)
```

Comment: Thanks. @Akku14